# Installing Windows 8 on virtual machine giving error

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macbook-pro

Well I've a pretty complicated hardware and software combination, so I am explaining the background first. I have a Macbook pro mid 2012 model with OSX Mountain Lion. I am dual booting it with Windows 7. Now I want to try out Windows 8, so that I can replace Windows 7 with Windows 8. So to try out I am using Oracle's VirtualBox to create a virtual PC and using Windows 8 trial (64 bit). All the three OS are 64 bit.

Now when I load the Win8 ISO (the ISO is in a usb drive), and boot from it in the virtual OS, there's some strange message coming from virtualbox which is

```
The virtual machine window is optimized to work in 32 bit color mode but the virtual display is currently set to 24 bit.

Please open the display properties dialog of the guest OS and select a 32 bit color mode, if it's available, for best possible performance of the virtual video subsystem.
```

and then there's a windows 8 blue screen which says

> Recovery Your PC needs to be repaired.

And then some `bootload.exe` is missing.

I am adding the screenshot of the error too

[image: Error]

Any idea on what's wrong here? or if I can do something about it?

Thanks!!

Comment: installing from osx or win7 boot? why run it from a usb drive and not hd?

Comment: Well I tried with hdd too, same issue. I am on win7.

Comment: 3d/2d acceleration? Go to Display -> Video and check Enable 2D Video Acceleration... and maybe try 3d.